# Elements display too early

Tags: javascript, caching

My JS is inserting an element on the page using `document.createElement('div')`. Then I also bind some hover events to show/hide the element when you hover over certain other page elements. The first time I load the page, it works perfectly. When I reload with a breakpoint set in the function where the element is being created, the element is present immediately on pageload but the breakpoint is never hit. This would be fine except my function also checks for the element and doesn't insert it if the ID is already there, in which case the hover binding doesn't happen. I think this could have to do with some kind of caching on the page (just making an uneducated guess there - I don't know anything about this).

It's not a page or app that I've developed, I'm writing Javascript that gets executed by a 3rd-party service on their page so the backend is not accessible to me other than what you can see in the console.

Is there any caching process that loads page elements that were there on the last pageload, even if they're supposed to be inserted asynchronously?

Comment: My best guess is that you might be getting bitten by hoisting (described here: http://www.sitepoint.com/back-to-basics-javascript-hoisting/).

Comment: My function is assigned to a variable, registered and executed by a dispatching function that loops through every registered function and calls them one by one. So hoisting shouldn't affect it, right? And even if it did, if the function is being run, execution should stop at my breakpoint. This is why I think the element is somehow getting stored in the DOM if that's possible.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Is it possible to put the code in a fiddle to replicate this bug? Also, if you're using Chrome, you can disable the cache when the developer tools are open (click the gear at the top right and then it's under 'General')

Comment: @GarrettKadillak - I don't know how I would begin to replicate this. Turning off caching didn't help.

Comment: I got around this problem by checking at the beginning of the script for the presence of the element and if it was there, deleting it. Still baffled, but this is a working solution.